# How do you unescape a XMPP JID?

Tags: objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

Is there a library for escaping and unescaping jids.  We're currently using the XMPPFramework available here https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework.  We could of course write our own, but I would think this would be a solved problem.

Below is the XEP.

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0106.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as yo can see in the XEP you linked Jid escaping is only replacing some characters. You don't need a full blown library and can do this in some lines of code.
Add it to XMPPFramework yourself and submit a patch when its missing there.